# Is there a way to run some clean up code when Gatling meets failure and before action like exithereiffailed

Tags: gatling

I just want to clean up data on DB when the Gatling scenario fails and before exithereiffailed. So that when I run Gatling again, the broken data on DB is already deleted.

Thanks a lot!

I just see there are tryMax, exithereiffailed such action, but they don't take a callback to do some clean up work.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the proper solution for this is automating a database restore.

Then, if you really want to implement such rollback from the Gatling side, you shouldn't try to rollback individual changes from each virtual user. Performing the rollbacks while the test is running would harm performance and your test results.
You should store the changes (in memory or disk) so that you can roll them back once the test is done, eg with a dedicated scenario triggered after your real one with `andThen`.